# Switching User From A sudoer to Bash to Root

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, sudo

On someone's ubuntu VPS I created a user, added them to sudo and logged in.
Figuring I didn't need the root password anymore, I got rid of it. Then for whatever reason I felt I needed to go back to root. 
I type in `sudo -s` and put in the users password. Then before my command it said something like

```
bash@name#
```

Then I could su root.

Just wondering what bash is, how I could switch to it before and I can't on my current vps.

Thanks :D

Comment: What is your actual question here? Are you *sure* it said `bash@name` not `root@name`? Have you read the manual page for sudo `man sudo` in particular the sections for `sudo -s` and `sudo -i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bash is Unix shell.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)

But without giving more information we can only guess what is there behind this behaviour. Relevant would be the line from `/etc/passwd` about this user (if it is real user) and content of `/etc/sudoers`.

My theory is that this `bash` user has `UID=0` as `root` and when you run `sudo` it is run under this user context (instead of root). But this QA site is not about playing such a games.

Comment: [link](https://youtu.be/GIM1HEhUdX8)
Just to show you what happens on my MacBook. 
The same thing when I typed in sudo -s happened on the VPS I was referring to.